# JavaScript alert mechanism not working

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want my script to behave such that on form submission, if none of radio button is checked, it should alert user to select one. I have written code but it isn't working. Help please.

```js
function validateRadios() {
  var c = document.getElementsByName("qualification");
  for(var a=0;a<=c.length;a++) {
    if(c[a].checked ) {
      alert("Form OK!");
      return true;
    }
  }
  alert("Please select one");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="return validateRadios();">
   Select your qualification     
  Intermediate<input type="radio" name="qualification" value="inter" />
  Bachelors<input type="radio" name="qualification" value="Bchlrs"/>
  Masters<input type="radio" name="qualification" value="mstrs"/>
 </br>
 <input type="submit" value="Lock details"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `but it isn't working` - please describe in what way it isn't working - do you get errors in the developer tools console perhaps? first hint: `a<=c.length` needs to be `a<c.length`

Comment: Your hint worked. It wasn't showing alert when none of radio button was checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your **for loop condition**.It is iterating till length+1 element.Just remove `=` condition and it will work.

```js
    function validateRadios() {
      var c = document.getElementsByName("qualification");
      for(var a=0;a<c.length;a++) {
        if(c[a].checked ) {
          alert("Form OK!");
          return true;
        }
      }
      alert("Please select one");
      return false;
    }
```

```html
     <form onSubmit="return validateRadios();">
     Select your qualification     
        Intermediate<input type="radio" name="qualification" value="inter" />
        Bachelors<input type="radio" name="qualification" value="Bchlrs"/>
        Masters<input type="radio" name="qualification" value="mstrs"/>
       </br>
       <input type="submit" value="Lock details"/>        
    </form>
```

Comment: @Ahmer-thanks.please accept the answer and upvote. It will help to others in future.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better this way :)

```
function validateRadios() {
  var status = false
  var c = document.getElementsByName("qualification").forEach((item) => {
    status = item.checked ? true : status
  })
  console.log(status)
}
```

And it does not work for you because it returns an array of not only elements but also with methods.